# Mysql Query return matched record plus extra record's which share the same valus of field "CID" of matched query record

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
Table1 Name:: user

```
| id  |  accnum | name  
|-----|---------|-------
| 1   |  111112 |Jhon S
| 2   |  111113 |Steven R
| 3   |  111114 |Ron S  
| 4   |  111115 |Alex R
| 5   |  111116 |Rony A
```

Table2 Name:: info

```
| userid  |  cid    | amount
|---------|---------|-------
| 1       |  31      |111
| 2       |  21      |121
| 3       |  31      |131  
| 4       |  41      |141
| 5       |  31      |151
```

Now, i need a mysql query which should result below on search with keyword "111114"
keyword search for table "user" field "accnum" return the matched accnum field row also return the row those are sharing the same "cid" value of info table of matched result.
e.g. "111114" is associated to user table "id"=>"3" name=>"Ron S" which having "cid"=>31 in info table.
Now the cid=31 value sharing other two row of users (1,5) .

The expected result will look like below::

```
| id  |  accnum | name    | cid
|-----|---------|---------|----
| 1   |  111112 |Jhon S   | 31
| 3   |  111114 |Ron S    | 31
| 5   |  111116 |Rony A   | 31
```

Please Help with a single mysql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by joining `user` to `info` twice and back to `user` again:

```
select u2.*, i2.cid
from user u1 
inner join info i1 on i1.userid = u1.id
inner join info i2 on i2.cid = i1.cid
inner join user u2 on u2.id = i2.userid
where u1.accnum = 111114
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vT46VJb7kU9NKB5dBUAX7C/0).
Results:

```
| id  | accnum | name   | cid |
| --- | ------ | ------ | --- |
| 1   | 111112 | Jhon S | 31  |
| 3   | 111114 | Ron S  | 31  |
| 5   | 111116 | Rony A | 31  |
```

Comment: Working as expected... Thanks @forpas

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `accnum` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO user
  (`id`, `accnum`, `name`)
VALUES
  ('1', '111112', 'Jhon S'),
  ('2', '111113', 'Steven R'),
  ('3', '111114', 'Ron S'),
  ('4', '111115', 'Alex R'),
  ('5', '111116', 'Rony A');

CREATE TABLE info (
  `userid` INTEGER,
  `cid` INTEGER,
  `amount` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO info
  (`userid`, `cid`, `amount`)
VALUES
  ('1', '31', '111'),
  ('2', '21', '121'),
  ('3', '31', '131'),
  ('4', '41', '141'),
  ('5', '31', '151');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select u1.id,u1.accnum,u1.name,i1.cid
from user u1
inner join info i1 on u1.id=i1.userid
inner join (select i2.cid as cid
from user u2 inner join info i2 on u2.id=i2.userid
and u2.accnum="111114") t on t.cid=i1.cid;
```

```
| id  | accnum | name   | cid |
| --- | ------ | ------ | --- |
| 1   | 111112 | Jhon S | 31  |
| 3   | 111114 | Ron S  | 31  |
| 5   | 111116 | Rony A | 31  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vT46VJb7kU9NKB5dBUAX7C/2)